# Could a conditional cause confusion between hypothetical and what happened?

Tags: conditional-constructions

I have a scenario where I would normally use a second conditional like this:

"If I wanted to, I could do this and that even now". Now from the context it was somewhat implicit, that it was something I could do, if I wanted to. So I ended up with something like "Like I said, I could do this and that" (with silent *if I wanted to*).

Is that the right conditional? And if so, how does listener know what I meant by "I could do this and that"?
Could they mix up between:

- I could and I actually did, and
- I could (I had and maybe still have the option to), but I didn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are situations where *could* can be ambiguous, since it is used both as a past tense of *can* and to express a hypothetical.

> - Did you have any unique skills when you were a kid?
>
> - I **could** speak English.

> - How are we going to communicate?
>
> - I **could** speak in English.

The context usually makes it clear whether you're referring to an actual situation in the past, or a possibility in the present/near future. Note that expressing an unrealized possiblility in the past (your "I could, but I didn't") will typically use Present Perfect after *could*:

> - How did you manage to communicate with him?
>
> - I **could have** spoken in English, but I opted for German.

[Here](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/can-and-could) is a good reference for the various uses of *can*/*could*.

Comment: Thanks. Is this even conditional, or is conditional only when we use "would" and not "could"?